# Assigning a fixed string to a dynamically changing ip

Tags: windows, networking

I currently have 3 windows machines connected to a central wifi. Now two of the machines have an old software installed on them that require the ip address of the 3rd machine. The problem is every time the 3rd machine restarts its ip address changes. I wanted to know what my options are for setting a fixed ip/hostname on the 3rd machine and what resources I need to look up on.My first thought was having a script run at startup that would map a string to 127.0.0.1 on the hosts file and hopefully DNS would map the string to the ipaddress of that machine.Kindly let me know if that would work. Also if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Create a reservation / fixed ip for the 3rd machine.

Comment: Are there any other options. My major concern is suppose the 3rd pc is (which hosts a server) is moved to a vicinity where they have more than 2 window machines and there is an ip address conflict. Not sure what the chances of that are but I wanted to know what other options i might have.

Comment: Deal with that if/when it happens by changing the fixed IP again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the third machine a fixed IP address and be done with it. You can do that even using wifi.